# How to echo to multiple topics at once

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use rostopic to echo multiple topics at once?

I have a node that's consuming a lot of CPU, and I'm not sure why. It publishes a dozen topics, so to help debug, I tried to do:

```
rostopic echo /mynode/*
```

but of course, rostopic told me the topic "/mynode/*" doesn't exist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245635/how-to-echo-to-multiple-topics-at-once/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can open multiple terminal windows/tabs and use `rostopic echo` in each one, or you spawn multiple copies of rostopic, all echoing to the console.

```
rostopic echo /nodename/topic1 & rostopic echo /nodename/topic2 & rostopic echo /nodename/topic3 & ...
```

But you might find it more useful to use `rostopic hz` or `rostopic bw` to see the publish rate or bandwidth for some of these topics. It may be more likely that your main loop is publishing faster than you need. Are you using a `rospy.Rate` to publish at regular intervals, as in [this rospy tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber)? (For the C++ code counterpart [see this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber).)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2